# Center a DIV to a nother using jQuery css

Tags: jquery, css

When there are multiple nested DIVs how do I set once of those DIVs to the center of another DIV.

Example:
I want to center `$('#thiWrapper)` to `$('#moveingDiv')`

```
$('#moveingDiv').css({
       left: $('#thiWrapper).width()/2 - $('#moveingDiv').width()/2 //doesNot work
});
```

html:

```
<div id="thiWrapper">
   <div id="moveingDiv"></div>
</div>
```

css

```
#moveingDiv{
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: need to see your HTML too.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you need to use JS for this?

Comment: @uʍopǝpısdn: nope, I'm open to ideas. thanks.

Comment: It works [here](http://jsfiddle.net/qyojb8zq/). It looks like you forgot a single quote, though, `'`.

Comment: Also, why do your id's have `#`'s in them?

Comment: @uʍopǝpısdn: that's a typo. fixed it. thanks.

Comment: Could do with seeing some more code. Are there any other styles applied to the two divs? width? display? etc

Comment: @uʍopǝpısdn: that's it. the width, height is dynamic.

Comment: Which element has a known width? `moveingDiv` ?

Comment: Are looking for both vertical and horizontal alignment?

Comment: @BenPearce: thanks. just horizontal alignment.

Comment: You just said that you are setting the width "that's it. the width, height is dynamic." ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the parent element (i.e. #thiWrapper) has a set width [this](https://jsfiddle.net/freb4rbw/1/) is a good way to achieve horizontal alignment in a div

html:

```
<div id="thiWrapper">
   <div id="moveingDiv"></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#thiWrapper{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:blue;
}

#moveingDiv{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:red;
    margin:auto;
}
```

If you're dead set on implementing this programmatically. The best way to do that is by creating a class containing the css attributes you want to add and adding that class to your element using jQuery's addClass() method. For example you replace the css in the example above with the css below.

```
#thiWrapper{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:blue;
}

#moveingDiv{
      width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:red;
}

.center{
    margin:auto;
 }
```

Then you can programmatically center #moveingDiv with the code below:

```
$("#moveingDiv").addClass(".center");
```

And programmatically un-center with the code:

```
$("#moveingDiv").removeClass(".center");
```

Comment: Not sure, I didn't cast the down vote. If you like this solution please let everyone know by clicking the check mark to the left of the question thus marking it as accepted.

Comment: I'd say use which ever one you end up implementing

Comment: I agree with @BenPearce. Mark the one that you found most helpful. You can always upvote multple answers anyway

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned in a comment that you are setting a width on the element you can use `margin: 0 auto` to centre the div..

```css
#thiWrapper {
    background: green;
}

#moveingDiv {
    position: relative;
    background: red;
    width: 50%;
  
    margin: 0 auto;
    
}
```

```html
<div id="thiWrapper">
   <div id="moveingDiv">HELLO</div>
</div>
```

If this isn't the case you can use a combination of  `inline-block` and `text-align: center`...

```css
#thiWrapper {
    background: green;
    
    text-align:center;
}

#moveingDiv {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: red;
    
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="thiWrapper">
   <div id="moveingDiv">HELLO</div>
</div>
```

Comment: nice... let me give it a try.

Comment: I would guess it was because you didn't originally post your HTML which meant your question was impossible to answer. Try to provide _all_ the relevant code in your question.There was still a little guess work required even with the code you posted.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you just have to look closely at what end result you need.

Example:  If you're wanting to center `#moveingDiv` inside its wrapper, `#thiWrapper`, you're going to want to take the width of the wrapper, subtract the width of the inner div from it to get the total margin on both sides of the inner div, and then divide that by 2 to get the width of the margin on one side of the inner div:

```
$('#moveingDiv').css({
    left: ($('#thiWrapper').width() - $('#moveingDiv').width()) / 2
});
```

Here's a [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bowheart/x58jn5nq/) if you want to take a look.

This can also be accomplished many ways easily in CSS, assuming you know the width of the inner div.  Here's an example using `calc()`:

```
#moveingDiv {
    position: relative;
    left: calc((100% - 100px) / 2);
    width: 100px;
}
```

Here's a [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bowheart/x58jn5nq/1/) using that.

Depending on the `display` and `position` attributes of the inner and outer blocks, you may even be able to do something much simpler, just setting `margin: auto`:

```
#moveingDiv {
    margin: auto;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Here's a [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bowheart/x58jn5nq/2/) with that one.

Comment: thanks. your answer is no different to mine? I'm looking for a solution which may contain `.offset()` or maybe `.position()`

Comment: My answer has a few key differences from yours.  And you really shouldn't need an offset for this since, from what I can tell, you are setting the initial position of the inner div here, and not modifying it from a previously set position.